# Probability algorithms for beginners

Tags: algorithm

For awhile now I've been looking into developing odds algorithms and probability models for.an experimental project whining is in essence like the webbot but focused on sociological events rather than stock performanc.

IAt the moment I'm brushing up on Game Theory and Statistics but if there are any specific resources or topics AI should hone in on, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This all works much better if you actually ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[thinkstats.com](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkstats/) is a good place to start for probability and statistics with a computational aspect.